# maven-release-plugin:2.5.1:perform failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

**maven-release-plugin:2.5.1:perform failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing**

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.1:perform (default-cli) on project eq-services-parent: 
Execution default-cli of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.1:perform failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:

maven-release-plugin:2.5.1:perform: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: SHALLOW

    [ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.1
    [ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below dependencies to your parent pom

```
<plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.5.1</version>
               <dependencies>
                   <dependency>
                       <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
                       <artifactId>maven-scm-api</artifactId>
                       <version>1.10.0</version>
                   </dependency>
                  <dependency>
                     <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
                     <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-gitexe</artifactId>
                     <version>1.10.0</version>
                  </dependency>
               </dependencies>
               <configuration>
                  <localCheckout>true</localCheckout>
                  <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
               </configuration>
</plugin>
```